# What can make nanosleep drift with exactly 10 sec on mac OS X 10.9

Tags: c++, macos, boost, osx-mavericks

A part of my program need to sleep for 10 milliseconds. Normally I use the boost lib for this, but it sometimes sleep for 10010 milliseconds, so I tried replacing

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(read_delay_ms));
```

with

```
struct timespec a;
a.tv_sec  = 0;
a.tv_nsec = read_delay_ms * 1000000;
int rc = nanosleep( &a, NULL );
```

Not surprisingly the use of nanosleep also sometimes sleep for 10010 milliseconds (sleep_for is implemented using nanosleep() on mac).

My program is complex so I have not been able to create a small example that illustrates the issue, I am working on this. Here are some highlights:

- It is a python extension written in C++ using boost::python as bridge
- Uses boost::threads for asynchrony tasks using boost::asio

The issue is only seen on mac OS X 10.9. It is not seen on Mac OS X 10.8 and below, and not seen on linux, win, iOS and android.

In order to find the error in either my code, boost lib or sys functions, any help or suggestions are more that welcome.

Comment: The gab is exactly 10 sec, I need to sleep for 10 milliseconds but it is sleeping 10 sec and 10 milliseconds.

Comment: @SteveJessop , my bad, missread :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Nap is most probably the reason for this. It was introduced in 10.9 and is already known for causing such surprises.

`NSProcessInfo` has new three methods for temporarily disabling App Nap: `beginActivityWithOptions:reason:`, `endActivity:`, `performActivityWithOptions:reason:block:`.

You can also disable it by writing boolean YES into `NSAppSleepDisabled` user default of your application's domain.

Comment: Apparently, "temporarily" means until an app or system restart.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a programmatic solution written in C that will compile and run on both older and newer OS X versions (i.e. you don't need 10.9 or to be working in Objective C to compile this).

Call `osx_latencycritical_start()` at the start of your program, or at least before timing critical operations begin.
Call `osx_latencycritical_end()` if your code is no longer doing timing critical work.

(The code is recursion safe, but not thread safe.
 I place this code in the public domain.)

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)

#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 1050
# include <objc/runtime.h>
# include <objc/message.h>
#else
# include <objc/objc-runtime.h>
#endif

/* Globals */
static int osx_latencycritical_count = 0;
static id osx_latencycritical_activity = nil;

/* Tell App Nap that this is latency critical */
void osx_latencycritical_start() {
    Class pic;      /* Process info class */
    SEL pisl;       /* Process info selector */
    SEL bawo;       /* Begin Activity With Options selector */
    id pi;          /* Process info */
    id str;         /* Reason string */

    if (osx_latencycritical_count++ != 0)
        return;

    /* Avoid triggering an exception when run on older OS X */
    if ((pic = (Class)objc_getClass("NSProcessInfo")) == nil)
        return;

    if (class_getClassMethod(pic, (pisl = sel_getUid("processInfo"))) == NULL)
        return;

    if (class_getInstanceMethod(pic,
          (bawo = sel_getUid("beginActivityWithOptions:reason:"))) == NULL)
        return;

    /* Get the process instance */
    if ((pi = objc_msgSend((id)pic, pisl)) == nil)
        return;

    /* Create a reason string */
    str = objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSString"), sel_getUid("alloc"));
    str = objc_msgSend(str, sel_getUid("initWithUTF8String:"), "Timing Crititcal");

    /* Start activity that tells App Nap to mind its own business: */
    /* NSActivityUserInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep */
    /* | NSActivityLatencyCritical */
    osx_latencycritical_activity = objc_msgSend(pi, bawo,
                    0x00FFFFFFULL | 0xFF00000000ULL, str);
}

/* Done with latency critical */
void osx_latencycritical_end() {
    if (osx_latencycritical_count > 0) {
        osx_latencycritical_count--;
        if (osx_latencycritical_count == 0
         && osx_latencycritical_activity != nil) {
            objc_msgSend(
                         objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSProcessInfo"),
                                      sel_getUid("processInfo")),
                                      sel_getUid("endActivity:"),
                                      osx_latencycritical_activity);
            osx_latencycritical_activity = nil;
        }
    }
}

#endif /* __APPLE__ */
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't compile on macOS 10.14. It doesn't like the NSString alloc call: `error: no matching function for call to 'objc_msgSend'... reason_string = objc_msgSend (objc_getClass ("NSString"), ... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/objc/message.h:85:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Class _Nullable' (aka 'objc_class *') to 'id _Nullable' (aka 'objc_object *') for 1st argument ... objc_msgSend(id _Nullable self, SEL _Nonnull op, ...)`. Is this maybe an API change in a newer version of macOS?