# How to disable OS X App Nap in C++?

Tags: c++, macos

Is there a way to disable App Nap from the source code of a C++ application?

I'm using the clang compiler with cmake.

Comment: If using Qt.io, and encountering this problem, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686488/qapplication-is-lazy-or-making-other-threads-lazy-in-the-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Foundation Release Notes for OS X 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000742-TRANSLATED_CHAPTER_965-10_9AppNap) gives some details on how and when App Nap is activated, and notes that the [`NSProcessInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class can be used to disable it (specifically, using `beginActivityWithOptions:reason:`).

There doesn't appear to be any C or C++ interface to App Nap.

Answer (score 3):

The following RAII class, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729281/1329652), will do it.

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)

#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 1050
# include <objc/runtime.h>
# include <objc/message.h>
#else
# include <objc/objc-runtime.h>
#endif
#include <mutex>

namespace detail { struct LatencyCriticalLock {
   int count = {};
   id activity = {};
   id processInfo = {};
   id reason = {};
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mutex_lock() {
      init();
      return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
   }
private:
   std::mutex mutex;
   template <typename T> static T check(T i) {
      return (i != nil) ? i : throw std::runtime_error("LatencyCrticalLock init() failed");
   }
   void init() {
      if (processInfo != nil) return;
      auto const NSProcessInfo = check(objc_getClass("NSProcessInfo"));
      processInfo = check(objc_msgSend((id)NSProcessInfo, sel_getUid("processInfo")));
      reason = check(objc_msgSend((id)objc_getClass("NSString"), sel_getUid("alloc")));
      reason = check(objc_msgSend(reason, sel_getUid("initWithUTF8String:"), "LatencyCriticalLock"));
   }
}; }

class LatencyCriticalLock {
   static detail::LatencyCriticalLock d;
   bool locked = {};
public:
   struct NoLock {};
   LatencyCriticalLock &operator=(const LatencyCriticalLock &) = delete;
   LatencyCriticalLock(const LatencyCriticalLock &) = delete;
   LatencyCriticalLock() { lock(); }
   explicit LatencyCriticalLock(NoLock) {}
   ~LatencyCriticalLock() { unlock(); }
   void lock() {
      if (locked) return;
      auto l = d.mutex_lock();
      assert(d.count >= 0);
      if (!d.count) {
         assert(d.activity == nil);
         /* Start activity that tells App Nap to mind its own business: */
         /* NSActivityUserInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep */
         /* | NSActivityLatencyCritical */
         d.activity = objc_msgSend(d.processInfo, sel_getUid("beginActivityWithOptions:reason:"),
                                   0x00FFFFFFULL | 0xFF00000000ULL, d.reason);
         assert(d.activity != nil);
      }
      d.count ++;
      locked = true;
      assert(d.count > 0 && locked);
   }
   void unlock() {
      if (!locked) return;
      auto l = d.mutex_lock();
      assert(d.count > 0);
      if (d.count == 1) {
         assert(d.activity != nil);
         objc_msgSend(d.processInfo, sel_getUid("endActivity:"), d.activity);
         d.activity = nil;
         locked = false;
      }
      d.count--;
      assert(d.count > 0 || d.count == 0 && !locked);
   }
   bool isLocked() const { return locked; }
};

detail::LatencyCriticalLock LatencyCriticalLock::d;

#endif /* __APPLE__ */
```