# Thread Sleeps Too Long on OS X When In Background

Tags: multithreading, macos, qt, sleep

I have a background thread in a Qt App on OS X used for collecting data. The thread is supposed to sleep for 100 ms between each iteration, but it doesn't always work properly. When the app is the topmost OS X app, the sleep works fine. But when it isn't, the sleep lasts an arbitrary amount of time, up to ~10 seconds, after about a minute of operation.

Here is a simple Cocoa app that demonstrates the problem (note .mm for objc++)

AppDelegate.mm:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <libgen.h>
using namespace std::chrono;

#define DEFAULT_COLLECTOR_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 10

namespace Helpers {
  uint64_t time_ms() {
    return duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
  }
}

std::thread _collectorThread;
bool _running;

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  _running = true;
  uint64_t start = Helpers::time_ms();
  _collectorThread =
  std::thread (
               [&]{
                 while(_running) {
                   uint64_t t1, t2;
                   t1 = Helpers::time_ms();
                   std::this_thread::sleep_for((std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>)(1000 / DEFAULT_COLLECTOR_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY));
                   t2 = Helpers::time_ms();
                   std::cout << (int)((t1 - start)/1000) << " TestSleep: sleep lasted " << t2-t1 << " ms" << std::endl;
                 }
               });    
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  _running = false;
  _collectorThread.join();
}


@end
```

stdout:

```
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms.  // Window is in background
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms.  // behind Xcode window
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
...
...
52 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
52 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
52 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
52 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
52 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
52 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
52 TestSleep: sleep lasted 322 ms. // after ~1 minute,
53 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms. // sleep gets way off
53 TestSleep: sleep lasted 499 ms
53 TestSleep: sleep lasted 1093 ms
54 TestSleep: sleep lasted 1086 ms
56 TestSleep: sleep lasted 1061 ms
57 TestSleep: sleep lasted 1090 ms
58 TestSleep: sleep lasted 1100 ms
59 TestSleep: sleep lasted 1099 ms
60 TestSleep: sleep lasted 1096 ms
61 TestSleep: sleep lasted 390 ms
61 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
61 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms   // click on app window
62 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms  // to bring it to foreground
62 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
```

On the other hand, the following complete program does not slow down:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <libgen.h>
using namespace std::chrono;

#define DEFAULT_COLLECTOR_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 10

namespace Helpers {
    uint64_t time_ms() {
        return duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool _running = true;
    uint64_t start = Helpers::time_ms();
    std::thread collectorThread = std::thread (
                [&]{
        while(_running) {
            uint64_t t1, t2;
            t1 = Helpers::time_ms();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for((std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>)(1000 / DEFAULT_COLLECTOR_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY));
            t2 = Helpers::time_ms();
            std::cout << (int)((t1 - start)/1000) << " TestSleep: sleep lasted " << t2-t1 << " ms" << std::endl;
        }
    });
    collectorThread.join();
    return 0;
}

// clang++ -std=c++14 -o testc++ main.cpp
```

stdout:

```
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
...
...
99 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
99 TestSleep: sleep lasted 105 ms
99 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
100 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
100 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
100 TestSleep: sleep lasted 104 ms
```

My original app was QML, also shows same slowing down behavior.

TestSleep.pro:

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Scroll")

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            width: parent.width
            model: 20
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                text: "Item " + (index + 1)
                width: parent.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#define DEFAULT_COLLECTOR_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 10

namespace Helpers {
    uint64_t time_ms() {
        return duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool _running = true;
    QThread *collectorThread = QThread::create(
//    std::thread collectorThread = std::thread (
                [&]{
        while(_running) {
            uint64_t t1;
            t1 = Helpers::time_ms();
            QThread::msleep(1000 / DEFAULT_COLLECTOR_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY);
//            std::this_thread::sleep_for((std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>)(1000 / DEFAULT_COLLECTOR_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY));
            t1 = Helpers::time_ms() - t1;
            std::cout << "TestUSleep: sleep lasted " << t1 << " ms" << std::endl;
        }
    });
    collectorThread->start();
    collectorThread->setPriority(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    int returnValue = app.exec();
//    collectorThread.join();
    collectorThread->quit();
    collectorThread->wait();
    collectorThread->deleteLater();
    return returnValue;
}
```

stdout:

```
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
0 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
1 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
...
...
63 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
63 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
63 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
63 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
63 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
63 TestSleep: sleep lasted 7069 ms  # slows down
70 TestSleep: sleep lasted 235 ms
70 TestSleep: sleep lasted 10100 ms
80 TestSleep: sleep lasted 7350 ms
88 TestSleep: sleep lasted 10100 ms
98 TestSleep: sleep lasted 3566 ms
101 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms
102 TestSleep: sleep lasted 3242 ms
105 TestSleep: sleep lasted 2373 ms
107 TestSleep: sleep lasted 100 ms  # click on main window
107 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms  # to put app on top
107 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms  # and back to normal
107 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms  # behavior
108 TestSleep: sleep lasted 101 ms
108 TestSleep: sleep lasted 102 ms
...
```

The behavior is the same when using std::thread instead of QThread (commented out in code).

Comment: Try increasing the priority of the thread.

Comment: See main.cpp. It's set to the highest priority level.

Comment: I just performed the same test on Linux, and it does not happen there.

Comment: Linux doesn't have per-thread priorities. `setPriority` does [nothing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#setPriority) if your thread isn't running.

Comment: @zneak - you are misunderstanding. On OS X, when I increase the priority, it does not help. On Linux, the problem does not exist.

Comment: Let me rephrase: there can't be a problem on Linux because it doesn't have per-thread priorities, and additionally, your `setPriority` call does nothing because it's a no-op until `start` (which also accepts an optional priority parameter) has been called.

Comment: update: I built a Cocoa App in Xcode with a main window, and started a POSIX thread in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching (no Qt). The problem occurs there as well.

Comment: Agreed. Actually I did fix the order of start and setPriority after seeing a compiler warning - forgot to update the question. Problem still occurs. I will add the Xcode example because it's a better test now.

Comment: @zneak Update: while setting the thread priority using QThread::setPriority did not work, setting the priority via pthread_setschedparam did. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it would work to use setPriority in the next run loop iteration instead of immediately after start()

Comment: You might have missed it, but the documentation link I posted (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#setPriority) says that start has an optional priority parameter. You could try that.

Comment: Answers don't belong in the questions. Please answer your own question if you have a solution and if the question is on-topic. Please also minimize the code in the question: this is not an enterprise project - having multiple files and unrelated cruft is sloppy.

Comment: @zneak, I didn't see a doc link, but I see the one you just posted. You mentioned that start has an optional priority parameter (I did miss that). I could try that, but it would be odd if if worked and setPriority did not? I'm just happy to have it working. Since thread priority is OS specific, it may not have been implemented on OS X.

Comment: That was in reply of your suggestion to try setPriority in the next run loop iteration.

Comment: oh yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Just tested turning off App Nap, and it has also fixed the problem. I guess a takeaway is that under App Nap, threads set as high priority do not get napped! Not sure which answer to mark as the solution, so I'll give it to the first responder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of Apple's power-saving [App Nap](https://www.howtogeek.com/277414/what-is-app-nap-is-it-slowing-down-my-mac-apps/) feature.

You can verify that it is App Nap that is the culprit by running Apple's Activity Manager program and looking in the "App Nap" column (you may need to right-click in the process table's header-bar to make that column visible first).  If your program is being app-napped, you will see a "Yes" in that column for your program's row in the table.

If you want to programatically disable app-nap for your program you can put this Objective-C++ file into your program and call the disable_app_nap() function at the top of main():

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foundation/NSProcessInfo.h>

void disable_app_nap(void)
{
   if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginActivityWithOptions:reason:)])
   {
      [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] beginActivityWithOptions:0x00FFFFFF reason:@"Not sleepy and don't want to nap"];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Sounds like this is good practice for any time-critical OS X app, so I'll try this in lieu of my solution and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to App Nap, and I can reproduce the issue on macOS 10.13.4. The example below reproduces it when `reproduce` is set to `true`. When set to `false`, the [`LatencyCriticalLock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49679984/1329652) takes care of ensuring that App Nap is not active.

Also note that sleep does not ensure that your operation runs with stated period - if the operation takes any time at all, even due to system load and latencies, the period will be longer than intended. The system timers on most platforms ensure that the average period is correct. The sleep-based pacing will always run at a period longer than desired.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/appnap-49677034
#if !defined(__APPLE__)
#error This example is for macOS
#endif
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <mutex>
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/message.h>

// see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49679984/1329652
namespace detail { struct LatencyCriticalLock {
   int count = {};
   id activity = {};
   id processInfo = {};
   id reason = {};
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mutex_lock() {
      init();
      return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
   }
private:
   std::mutex mutex;
   template <typename T> static T check(T i) {
      return (i != nil) ? i : throw std::runtime_error("LatencyCrticalLock init() failed");
   }
   void init() {
      if (processInfo != nil) return;
      auto const NSProcessInfo = check(objc_getClass("NSProcessInfo"));
      processInfo = check(objc_msgSend((id)NSProcessInfo, sel_getUid("processInfo")));
      reason = check(objc_msgSend((id)objc_getClass("NSString"), sel_getUid("alloc")));
      reason = check(objc_msgSend(reason, sel_getUid("initWithUTF8String:"), "LatencyCriticalLock"));
   }
}; }

class LatencyCriticalLock {
   static detail::LatencyCriticalLock d;
   bool locked = {};
public:
   struct NoLock {};
   LatencyCriticalLock &operator=(const LatencyCriticalLock &) = delete;
   LatencyCriticalLock(const LatencyCriticalLock &) = delete;
   LatencyCriticalLock() { lock(); }
   explicit LatencyCriticalLock(NoLock) {}
   ~LatencyCriticalLock() { unlock(); }
   void lock() {
      if (locked) return;
      auto l = d.mutex_lock();
      assert(d.count >= 0);
      if (!d.count) {
         assert(d.activity == nil);
         /* Start activity that tells App Nap to mind its own business: */
         /* NSActivityUserInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep */
         /* | NSActivityLatencyCritical */
         d.activity = objc_msgSend(d.processInfo, sel_getUid("beginActivityWithOptions:reason:"),
                                   0x00FFFFFFULL | 0xFF00000000ULL, d.reason);
         assert(d.activity != nil);
      }
      d.count ++;
      locked = true;
      assert(d.count > 0 && locked);
   }
   void unlock() {
      if (!locked) return;
      auto l = d.mutex_lock();
      assert(d.count > 0);
      if (d.count == 1) {
         assert(d.activity != nil);
         objc_msgSend(d.processInfo, sel_getUid("endActivity:"), d.activity);
         d.activity = nil;
         locked = false;
      }
      d.count--;
      assert(d.count > 0 || d.count == 0 && !locked);
   }
   bool isLocked() const { return locked; }
};

detail::LatencyCriticalLock LatencyCriticalLock::d;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   struct Thread : QThread {
      bool reproduce = {};
      void run() override {
         LatencyCriticalLock lock{LatencyCriticalLock::NoLock()};
         if (!reproduce)
            lock.lock();
         const int period = 100;
         QElapsedTimer el;
         el.start();
         QTimer timer;
         timer.setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
         timer.start(period);
         connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&el]{
            auto const duration = el.restart();
            if (duration >= 1.1*period) qWarning() << duration << " ms";
         });
         QEventLoop().exec();
      }
      ~Thread() {
         quit();
         wait();
      }
   } thread;

   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   thread.reproduce = false;
   thread.start();

   QPushButton msg;
   msg.setText("Click to close");
   msg.showMinimized();
   msg.connect(&msg, &QPushButton::clicked, &msg, &QWidget::close);

   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the QThread example. Yes, I'm aware that the sleep will not give me precise timing. I'm processing some data periodically and since the data is buffered it's not necessary for the refresh rate to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution which worked in this case was to increase the thread priority using the c function pthread_setschedparam, if for some reason you want an App that Naps with a background thread that does not.

```
  int priority_max = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_RR);
  struct sched_param sp;
  sp.sched_priority = priority_max;
  pthread_setschedparam(_collectorThread.native_handle(), SCHED_RR, &sp);
```